# iOS app submission - archive does not contain an info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to submit an archive to the app store with an old app i was given.  I keep receiving two errors  CFBundleShortVersionString key must be in the plist and more troubling 'the package does not contain a plist'

Both of these items exist in the app.  I added the CFBundleShortVersionString key to the plist, and the plist file most definitely exists or I could never build it.  What is the issue here?

Comment: In your "Build Settings" on your target what do you see in the "Info.plist File" section?

Comment: @aus10c the name of the plist file and a couple of other settings.  What am i looking for?

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing that ev0lution wrote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the upload tool isn't finding your .plist file, that would be why it doesn't think it contains a CFBundleShortVersionString key. For some reason, apps can compile without any plist file at all!

First, make sure that your plist file exists in your project navigator, and that it's not highlighted in red. (in case it has been removed or renamed on disc, for whatever reason)

In your project in Xcode, select your app's target, and then select the "Build Settings" tab. Search for "plist" to filter the results. Under "Packaging", check the value of "Info.plist". This should be the name of your plist file, relative to your Xcode project. For example, "MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist". If it is blank, change it to the name of your plist file and rebuild.

Comment: The value under "Packaging" is 'appName-plist'.  There is no path.  However the plist is located in some sub directories of the project.  That path being "MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist.  So I will add the first part and see if it works.

Comment: @JMD If it's located in subdirectories (actual directories, not just Xcode groups) then I believe they should be prefixed to the path. I'm not too sure about what Xcode does currently, but it used to create the plist file inside an AppName folder, which was included in the Info.plist setting. I've tested it just then and without the folder name, the plist file is not found.

Comment: I thought it was in a subdirectory, but it was really just an xcode group.

Comment: adding the "MyApp" to the start of the path didn't work.  It couldnt find it for building the archive.  This is what is so weird, if I alter the path of the plist then building fails because it cant find the plist file.  But when the archive is made and i try to submit it, the error says its not there.

Comment: @JMD That's not good! Have you tried cleaning your project? Product -> Clean, and hold the Option key to get Product -> Clean Build Folder

Comment: i have cleaned but not the build folder.  trying that now

Comment: This app was pretty old, so I fixed this by copying a new plist file from a newly created app into the project.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I just added a new row with the key `Bundle versions string, short` to the Info.plist with the version for a value and then it passed validation with no further errors.

Answer (score 4):

In my case : i got this error message the first time I tried to upload the archive. However the 2nd time I tried to compile again, the computer was out of hard disk space and it seems like it didn't write to the plist file because of that reason the first time as well.

After freeing hard disk space and trying again (after restarting XCode too), it worked fine.

Comment: this was interesting solution. just in case, remove the xcode cache time to time. 

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`  saved +40GB for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had an wrong/errant entry in the info.plist for Executable File name, I replaced it with ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and that cleared the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have already "Bundle versions string, short" in my info.plist but the problem for me was "Bundle Display Name" is not in info.plist so i added that and it works.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you have **app extensions** embedded in your app, you must check (enable) the target membership of MainApp-Info.plist to those **app extensions** as well as the main app.  Do it in the Xcode file inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has published [a technical document that lists the possible issues that can cause this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1273/_index.html). As of today:

- missing CFBundlePackageType
- missing CFBundleShortVersionString
- missing CFBundleVersionString

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same two error messages. The Info.plist was in fact in the package, but it did not contain the CFBundleShortVersionString. The first error (Archive does not contain Info.plist) is given by the Apple system by mistake.

In my case I had several targets in the project, and I had added the CFBundleShortVersionString to the wrong target (not the one I was validating with Apple).

To be extra-sure, do

- export the archive in question for ad-hoc distribution
- unzip the *.ipa file
- Inspect the Payload/your.app/Info.plist file
- Check whether it contains the CFBundleShortVersionString

Answer (score 0):

for me, I had duplicated a Target a while back and the build settings were referencing a non-existing binary "myApp copy"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get meaningful error from uploader:

1. Install https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen
2. Create IPA: ipa build
3. Submit IPA: ipa distribute:itunesconnect -e -w -a ACCOUNT_NAME -p PASSWORD -f ./AppName.ipa -i APPLE_ID_OF_THE_APP --verbose

By doing this I received the following error: 
ERROR ITMS-90183: "Invalid Bundle OS Type Code. The value of 'Bundle OS Type Code' [CFBundlePackageType] in your application bundle's Info.plist file must be one of [APPL]."

Added CFBundlePackageType and my app passed validation!

I think this way you can find other issue if any during submission with more meaningful message.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit your plist file. Just set the **Build number** (right under the Version number in Targets - General). This will propagate into the plist file as **Bundle Version**.

It happened to me too, I deleted the build number and the result was your error. When I inserter just 1, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that `Target Membership` (in File Inspector) for Info.plist shows your project selected. In my case it wasn't. Ticking the checkbox resolved both problems.

Comment: When I do I get build failed... Multiple build commands produce...