# Xamarin Mono Application Entitlements missing

Tags: cocoa, mono, xamarin, sandbox, entitlements

I can successfully archive/build my application and use it without any issue, but i can't validate it for the AppStore.

Validating the archive with Xamarin results in the following Error:
"Archive does not include an Info.plist"

(opening the archive package in the finder shows that the Info.plist is available)

Validating the archive with Xcode Organizer results in an Alert Dialog

[image: Error Dialog]

Following errors are in the logs:

[OPTIONAL] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "*/Applications/My.app" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.

[OPTIONAL] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "No file at */Applications/My.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile'

The App is an embedded resource of an other App and as a resulting Validation Error i get the following message:

App sandbox not enabled for My.app/Contents/MacOS/My

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Mac application?

Comment: No it is only Mono:OSX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930104/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-iphone-build  Related?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132038/ios-app-submission-archive-does-not-contain-an-info-plist

Comment: @Owain CFBundleShortVersionString is set. Even in the plist in the .app

Comment: @Slartibartfast  Another app made in Xcode is working just fine. The Problem is with Xamarin.